# How to proof an open set and its complement contained in a metric space with infinite element are both infinite?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let X be a set containing infinitely many elements, and let d be a metric
on X. Prove that X contains an open set U such that U and its complement
$U^c$ = X\U are both infinite.

Comment: you mean infinite countable? Or not necessarily?